# What should be done about duplicates of unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion

Regarding [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224029/why-wont-4-women-give-birth?lq=1) and [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224067/why-wont-3-of-my-women-who-have-been-pregnant-for-about-24-hours-give-birth?lq=1). Both are duplicates of [this question with no good answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223916/why-dont-my-female-dwellers-give-birth-to-children?rq=1)

Since the original question has no good answers- just a few spammy answers and one guess, the other two can't be closed as dupes. People have already commented with links, but what else should be done?

Leaving the questions open is the obvious answer but just feels wrong. There is no reason why the duplicates should ever be answered- we should focus on getting the original answered.

Closing as another reason is possible but, again, feels like a poor and clumsy solution.

Finally, it'd be possible to upvote the guess from the original simply so the dupes can be closed as such. This feels extremely dishonest however.

Comment: Mod flag?  Can mods cast a dup vote on them?

Comment: Mods can merge questions, which carries over answers.

Comment: Note that question age shouldn't really be a factor to consider when duping one to the other. First quality of questions and answers, then viewcount/activity. This way we make sure that the people looking for answers are finding them

Comment: A workaround: Upvote the answer from the original question, vote to close the duplicate questions, then revert your upvote.